# NTP deamon runs slow

Tags: centos, ntp

I have been using the NTP protocol for a while. Lately, I have encountered a strange issue. Namely, when I try to print a list of the peers known to the server it takes around 20 seconds. Earlier it took less time.

```
[root@centos-test centos]# time ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*ntp1.tp.pl      .MRS.            1 u   18   64    3    2.093   -0.021   0.098
 ntp2.tp.pl      .MRS.            1 u   22   64    3    2.404    0.120   0.041
 96-7.cpe.smnt.p 149.156.70.75    2 u   27   64    3   22.526   -2.296   0.089
 ntp.wide-net.pl 194.146.251.101  2 u   30   64    3   65.808   -8.530   0.049

real    0m20.180s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.011s
```

I have restarted everything. I have changed the pools but without any significant effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it may be an issue with your DNS resolvers.

When you ask `ntp` for peer or host details by default it will try and resolve the reverse DNS names for any listed hosts. If your resolvers are slow, or there are DNS issues then that will hang your response and explain the situation you are seeing.

If you try the same command with the `-n` flag that will tell `ntp` to only return the IP addresses and not attempt a DNS lookup.

The command in your case would be; `time ntpq -p -n` I'd suggest that you check what DNS servers you have setup in `/etc/resolv.conf` and change them - but do note, if your host gets its own IP address via DHCP then the `resolv.conf` might get updated when your address refreshes, or changes.